# Bower Can't find Git Installation

Tags: ubuntu, bower, bower-install

I am running bower on ubuntu 14.04, with git installed for sure. I am using a command in makefile as below(which is called via another php script, triggered remotely):

```
/usr/local/binbower install
```

Its giving me the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/bower install
bower bootstrap#*               ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH
make: *** [dependency-install] Error 1
```

However, if I run the command by myself from terminal, it works. So, I am in puzzle, what might be wrong here?

I already found stackoverflow thread with similar error message, but their issue on different environment(windows) which doesn't match my case.

Comment: /usr/local/binbower install

you missed / after bin?

Answer (score 12):

I was facing this same issue on my Ubuntu. Solved after installed git again

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Comment: Very interesting. With ubuntu 15.x in virtualbox, I also have this issue. After reinstall git, everything working well...

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to file permissions. Run bower install with sudo and --allow-root option. This worked for me.